# ResultSet not returning results of CQL query in DataStax 4.2

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax

I'm using Datastax 4.2 and Cassandra 3.11.4. I have 3 nodes deployed and am trying to execute query, but ResultSet doesn't return the value. However, in datastax version 3.7.2 it returns the value. I think they have changed the output format, but I can't figure it out.

```
CqlSession sessionOne = CqlSession.builder().addContactPoint(addrSocOne).withLocalDatacenter("us-east-2").withKeyspace("test").build();
String query = "select id FROM samplequeue";
ResultSet rs = sessionOne.execute(query);
System.out.println(rs);
sessionOne.close();
```

The output is : com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.SinglePageResultSet

It does not contain the value of id, whereas in the previous version it did. Can anyone help me resolve the op? I need the value of id. It works fine from backend. I have already tried looping the resultset with row, but op is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try something like this (Assuming it's an INT - otherwise choose your datatype)?:

```
for (Row row : rs) {
                 System.out.println("Item: " +  row.getInt("item"));
         }
```